# Regex Find & Replace - Find string of any character and specific length then replace 1 character

Tags: regex

I have a document that has a range of numbers like this:

```
0300010000000394001001,27
0300010000000394001002,0
0300010000000394002001,182
0300010000000394002002,51
0300010000000394003001,156
0300010000000394003002,40
```

I need to find the new line character and replace with a number of spaces depending on the string length.
If it has 24 characters like this - 0300010000000394001002,0 then I need to replace the new line character at the end with 5 blank spaces.
If it has 25 characters like this - 0300010000000394002002,51 then I need to replace the new line character at the end with 4 blank spaces and so on.

In my text editor I can use find and replace. I search for the line length by `^(.|\s){24}$` for 24 characters - but this will obviously replace the whole line and I only need to replace the new line character at the end.

I want to specify a new line character AFTER  `^(.|\s){24}$`. Is this possible?

Comment: You just want to pad each line with blanks on the right end so that the result has 29 characters?  What if a line length is greater than 29 characters?

Comment: Yes, it's in a .DAT file and I'm not exactly sure how it's being read but it relates to a product SKU of 22 characters followed by a comma then the inventory count. The total characters before the next entry is 29 characters. I basically want to remove the line break and replace with the right number of spaces depending on the previous number of characters in the string.

Comment: Would you take a sed, awk, or python solution to this or are you looking specifically for a way to do this in your editor?  What scripting languages to you have access to (this is, after all, a site for programming questions. :) )

Comment: Thanks Ray, unfortunately I'm not familiar with sed, awk or python so I would have liked to do it in a language I'm familiar with. The issue ultimately was solved by another developer in house.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need two things.

1. [Multi-line Mode](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) (See "Using ^ and $ as Start of Line and...")
2. Backreferencing

Most editors that support regex support these naturally, but you'll have to let us know what editor you're using for us to be specific.  Without knowing what editor you're using, all I can say is that you want to do some combination of the following:

```
regex           subst
-----           -----
^(.{24})\n      $1     <-- there are spaces here
^(.{24})^M      \1     <-- there are spaces here
^(.{24})\s        ^^^^^
```